# Jquery trigger click event not working for a P element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to "make a para (in a div) editable and automatically show cursor in para" when clicked on edit icon. The para does becomes editable but cursor stays with the edit icon. I've read almost all answers regarding click event on SO, nothing helped.

This is my code
JS:
//Add a icon in para containing div when hover on div

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.editable', function () {
    $(this).append('<i class="pull-right ml-auto edit-content-icon fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>')
})

//Make para content editable and show cursor in para    
$(document).on('mousedown touchdown', '.edit-content-icon', function (e) {
    $(this).prev('p').prop('contentEditable', 'true')
    $(this).prev('p').click()
})
```

HTML:

```
<div id="some" class="editable col-md-9 col-lg-6 d-flex ">
   <p class="ml-md-3 my-auto">My Para...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Appending of icon was not showing due to incorrect formatting, I've made the necessary changes. Once the icon is appended para will have sibling.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s749f5cx/  It seems to work fine, though the click for (I assume) focus isn't doing anything afaik.

Comment: Yes, just like your fiddle, focus (which I'm trying to do with a click) doesn't go to para, even with .focus it doesn't work.

Comment: You have to use `focus()` *and* you need to change the event from `mousedown` to `mouseup`.  Because part of the logic related to clicking that `i` tag is to put focus on it.  So if you move focus to the `p` tag before that chain finishes, the click of the `i` is just going to put it right back on that `i` tag.